# What is optimal approach to create DAGs for multiple clients with different auth_info but same logic of pull data from API and push into DB?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am beginner in Airflow. I want to create a pipeline in Airflow which will pull data from API and insert into BigQuery. This same Operation I want to do for multiple clients stored into the database. Could you please suggest the optimal way to implement it?
Should we create a single DAG which will loop through each client’s metadata (authentication info, db name, table name etc), connect to API, fetch the data and insert into Bigquery db. Or should we have a separate DAG for each client which will be created dynamically so that all clients pipeline would be isolated from each other and if any one fails will not impact others etc? Could you please guide?

Comment: Hi! do you have any updates/new insights w.r.t. this topic?